# Collapse all other boxes as one box open.. shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have three boxes in shiny dashboard. i want to collapse all other boxes as i click on a box to open it.

For example:

```
if i click on box1 to open
box2 and box3 collapse

if I click on box2 to open 
box1 and box3 collapse

if I click on box3 to open 
box1 and box2 collapse
```

Comment: You actually only need to collapse one of the boxes, because in your design only one of them will be visible. So save a reference to active box somewhere, and on click collapse the active one and then reassign clicked box to be the new active.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `shinyBS::bsCollapsePanel`

Comment: `bs_accordian` from `bsplus` package is what you are looking for. Have a look at [this](http://ijlyttle.github.io/bsplus/articles/accordion.html) link